# pygame object not subscriptable

Tags: pygame, typeerror

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Austin\PycharmProjects\Project\pygame\pygame1.py", line 
84, in <module>
    redrawGameWindow()
  File "C:\Users\Austin\PycharmProjects\Project\pygame\pygame1.py", line 
34, in redrawGameWindow
    win.blit(walkLeft[walkCount//3], (x, y))
TypeError: 'pygame.Surface' object is not subscriptable
```

Error occurs when I move the picture I am using as my avatar left and right. Can't quite figure out what to change. I am following along this YouTube video to just look into pygame: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UdsNBIzsmlI

As far as I can tell his code is the same as mine except for my images being different.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

pygame.display.set_caption("First Game")

walkLeft = pygame.image.load('adnan_leftWalk.png')
walkRight = pygame.image.load('adnan_rightWalk.png')
bg = pygame.image.load('Game1.jpg')
char = pygame.image.load('adnanJump.png')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()


x = 50
y = 425
width = 64
height = 64
vel = 5
left = False
right = False
walkCount = 0
isJump = False
jumpCount = 10

def redrawGameWindow():
    global walkCount
    win.blit(bg, (0,0))
    if walkCount + 1 >= 27:
        walkCount = 0
    if left:
        win.blit(walkLeft[walkCount//3], (x, y))
        walkCount += 1
    elif right:
        win.blit(walkRight[walkCount//3], (x, y))
        walkCount += 1
    else:
        win.blit(char, (x,y))

    pygame.display.update()


run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(27)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > vel:
        x -= vel
        left = True
        right = False
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 460:
        x += vel
        right = True
        left = False
    else:
        right = False
        left = False
        walkCount = 0
    if not (isJump):
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            isJump = True
            right = False
            left = False
            walkCount = 0
    else:
        if jumpCount >= -10:
            neg = 1
            if jumpCount < 0:
                neg = -1
            y -= (jumpCount ** 2) * 0.5 * neg
            jumpCount -= 1

        else:
            isJump = False
            jumpCount = 10

    redrawGameWindow()


pygame.quit()
```

I want my avatar to be able to move left and right but can't quite seem to figure it out. This is my first experience with pygame.

Answer (score 0):

This code reads like the `walkLeft` should be a list of images to animate walking.  However, in the question's code, `walkLeft` is a single image:

```
walkLeft = pygame.image.load('adnan_leftWalk.png')
```

So it seems a bit mixed-up.

The error message the code is producing - `object is not subscriptable`, means the code tried to use array-notation (technically, it tried to use the `__getitem__()` property), but the object in question is not an array/list.

The line with the error:

```
 win.blit(walkLeft[walkCount//3], (x, y))  # ERROR HERE
```

Makes me think `walkLeft` should be a list of images, since it's using array/list notation on the variable, and `walkCount` is clamped to a maximum of `27`., but the integer-division by 3, does not make sense either (maybe there was 3 images of animation?).  Simply removing the array-notation **may** shed some light on the issue:

```
 win.blit(walkLeft, (x, y))  # Fixes the bug, somewhat
```

... and allow the code to function, drawing the same bitmap, but at different locations.  But it's pretty obvious something is missing.  Could the code a combination of two (or more) examples?

Comment: I think I see what you’re saying. It’s probably not working because the code I was following along in the YouTube video had Multiple images set up with walkLeft while mine only has one. I’ll play around with it more today. Thanks for the input!